# how to flush sediment out of my water pipes

Tags: plumbing

I have no water pressure in any of my water sources. when i first turned them on rust and thick nasty stuff came out. how do i flush them out without replacing the faucet themselves? I already tried letting them run for 20 min as high as they will go and it didn't work. please help.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't an easy solution for this.  Normally if you think there is a huge sediment problem then you need to contact local water company.  They will probably unhook your meter and then cut your pipe somewhere near where it enters your house.  They will then used compressed air to blow all of the sediment out.

My local water company had to do this a few years ago.  I noticed a huge decrease in pressure after they did some "construction".  It took them about an hour and there was a noticeable difference.  Now if there is sediment (less common) in the pipes in your house this is the same process except much harder.

Basically you have to isolate each branch and clear the branch of water.  Then you need to make sure there are no filters anywhere that would catch the sediment.  Means taking out shower head, disconnecting all sinks (hoping you have shut-off valves), taking filters out of shower valves... It would be an all day project for a plumber and there might not be that much gain.

Answer (score 3):

From the least expensive perspective, I would check an outdoor faucet if you have one.  These typically do not have a pressure regulators/aerators on the tip.

Next check for pressure regulators/aerators on your interior faucets.  Try putting your finger at the end of your faucet and if you feel some sort of a mesh and not a open hole you have a you have some sort of a tip.  Try to remove the tip, some are hand tight some need some persuasion by covering with a rag and use a wrench to remove.

Try running the water.  Try removing the supply to the faucet and determine if you have water to going to the fixture.  If this does not work, I would check for an interior shut off valve, try turning off and on the valve.  A object may be stuck in the value.

Next step would be checking the interior to see if you a receiving water into the location.  If you have water pressure at the interior shutoff and still no pressure in the house you have a blockage somewhere in the system.  You have to try them one at a time to determine approximate location.  Unfortunately you will have to call a plumber or correct the issue yourself.

If you have no supply entering your location, it may be the water company responsibility give them a call.